# Office JavaScript API: selecting a range in Word for Mac

Tags: ms-word, office365, ms-office, office-js, office365-apps

I'm working on a side project using the Microsoft Office JavaScript APIs. I have some functionality working to select a range in order to scroll to a particular position within a document. This works as expected in Office for the web, but in Office for Mac I get the following error when calling `context.sync().then()`:

Unhandled Promise Rejection: RichApi.Error: ItemNotFound

I can't find any documentation on that particular error, and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot what I might be doing wrong. What am I missing? Like I said, this works in the web interface.

Here is minimal sample of code that demonstrates the problem:

```
function UI(context) {
    this.context = context;
}

UI.prototype.initialize = function() {
    var paragraphs = this.context.document.body.paragraphs;
    this.context.load(paragraphs);

    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
        this.context.sync().then(() => {
            this.goToRange(paragraphs.items[0]);
        });
    });
};

UI.prototype.goToRange = function(range) {
    range.select();
    this.context.sync();
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    Office.onReady(() => {
        Word.run(context => {
            return context.sync().then(() => {
                new UI(context).initialize();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The only thing I can think of is that maybe the reference to the paragraph client object becomes "stale" in some sense, perhaps based on some resource limits that are lower in the Mac application than in the online interface? (That would be counterintuitive to me, but it's the only thing that comes to mind.)

Comment: When a Promise-related error occurs on one platform, but not another, the suspicion is that the code is not handling asynchronicity properly, but on the "good" platform, the timing works out such that _by luck_ everything finishes in the desired order. I can't find a way to get your code snippet into a `Word.run` callback that doesn't create syntax errors related to Promise handling. Please create a simple reproduction of the problem in [Script Lab](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/wa104380862) and post the code.

Comment: @RickKirkham Thanks for your response! I've updated the question with a full working code sample. That said, while _writing_ that sample I think I discovered the issue. I will post an answer.

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out the problem. I stumbled upon a hint while putting together the minimum code sample in the question; I removed a little too much code at first and encountered the following error:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: RichApi.Error: The batch function passed
>   to the ".run" method didn't return a promise. The function must return
>   a promise, so that any automatically-tracked objects can be released
>   at the completion of the batch operation.

I believe the issue is that, at least in Word for Mac, you can't use the `context` object provided by `Word.run` in an asynchronous event listener. I'm guessing this is because, as the above error states, some state has been released after resolving the promise returned. I can get the code to work by adding a dedicated call to `Word.run` (and using the fresh `context` provided) inside the event listener.

It is still a little odd that it works just fine in the browser. Presumably, the same state is not released as aggressively in the browser-based version.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I couldn't figure out where my `context` issue was coming from!